# Is it possible to have a cron job on my shared server which pushes desktop notifications to me?

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, cron

So I have a few websites I need to check very regularly for updated stock.

These websites do not offer an RSS feed of any sort, but I can write a script to scrape their pages and find out if they've updated.

Next step, I want to run this script as a cron job on my shared web server (possible) so that it runs every 10 minutes or so.

But I now want the same cron to push a desktop notification to me if there is an update. Is this possible? I know gmail has desktop notifications which work without having the website open, so I feel as though it's possible.

But am not sure where to start. Is there a library in PHP which allows this?

Comment: Check this --- [How to create cron job using PHP?] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: I know how to create a cron, but that's not what I'm asking here.